# Why is "every 1 min" the only schedule I can get working with later.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, laterjs

I have a working later schedule (in nodejs and typescript):

```
var sched = later.parse.text('every 1 min'),
    t = later.setInterval(this.repeater.bind(this), sched),
    count = 5;
```

which successfully calls the 'repeater' method (just console logs for now) every minute. So far so good.

But if I change the text "`every 1 min`" to practically anything else it doesn't do anything. At the bottom of the page at https://bunkat.github.io/later/parsers.html#overview there is a bunch of examples. None of them work, and none of them error out.

For example, if I pick a time in the future, like say 10:00 am is in the future, changing the text to "`at 10:00 am`" won't do anything. Error is -1, indicating no error. But the repeater method never gets called, no matter what text I try. What is going on?

I tried another syntax:

```
var uh = {
    schedules:
        [
            { h: [10], m: [36,37,38] },
            { h: [17], m: [30] }
        ],
    exceptions: [ ]
};

later.setInterval(this.repeater.bind(this), uh);
```

Again, no errors, but method is not called. Does the schedule only start at midnight or something? Do I have to wait until tomorrow to see if my tests work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found this http://www.javascriptoo.com/later which logs when the timers are going to expire **Tomorrow!**
Sure would be nice if the documentation said something about it...